# Association between Sedentary Time and Hypoglycemic Events in a 7-Day Analysis

Tags: r, biostatistics

I am conducting a study aiming to determine whether repetitive sedentary time over 7 consecutive days is associated with hypoglycemic events during the same period. Here are my variables:

Independent Variable: Sedentary time (measured over 7 days using accelerometry)

Dependent Variable: Hypoglycemic events, daily average blood glucose levels (measured over the same 7 days using continuous glucose monitoring)

Covariates: Daily insulin dosage, daily carbohydrate intake

I would like to gather opinions or suggestions on the most appropriate statistical approach to analyze these associations. Any advice on specific statistical models or additional considerations I should take into account would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1736031-association-between-sedentary-time-and-hypoglycemic-events-in-a-7-day-analysis

Comment: Welcome to CV, Loyd.  It always is a good idea to ask these kinds of questions before collecting your data.  However, that makes your question a little too open-ended for us to address in this forum.  Maybe we can focus it by first considering some basic issues.  Why do you elect to analyze daily averages?  Those aren't "events" *per se*: if "continuous" means much more frequently than once a day, then they are only a (crude) summary of blood glucose levels.  Using the averages seems to threaten your ability to conclude *anything* about transient hypoglycemic events.

Comment: Adding to what whuber said, the window for your rolling averages is also good to think about. Will you do last-7-day moving averages, for each day? Or will they blocked as non-overlapping 7-day periods? Or going the other way, if the continuous glucose monitoring and accelerometry is hourly, you could have hourly 168-hour moving average windows. That gives you a lot more data and detail, but time of day now needs to be accounted for. (Which makes everything more complicated, but is also great as it might tell you being less sedentary at a certain time of day is key.)